# Struts 2.5.12: Text tag displays name of the field from model class instead of value

Tags: struts2

I am uppgrading one of the project from Struts 2.3.3 to 2.5.12 and I see that in the upgraded project `<s:text />` tag is unable to display the value of the field from model class and instead it just displays the name. It works perfectly fine when I use Struts 2.3.3.

**My Action class is like:**

```
public class MyAction {
    private Member member;
    
    public Member getMember() {
        return member;
    }
}
```

**My model classes are like:**

```
public class Member implements Serializable {
    private Address address;
    
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}

public class Address implements Serializable {
    private String city;
    
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
}
```

**In the JSP, I have:**

```
<s:text name="member.address.city" />
```

The output I see on page is `member.address.city`, where as I am expecting the value of the city.

I see in debug mode that control is coming to the `getCity()` method of `Address` class and the `city` field has the value `London`, but still it doesn't get displayed in UI.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: `<s:text>` is for i18n.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/docs/text.html):

> If the named message is not found in a property file, then the body of
>   the tag will be used as default message. If no body is used, then the
>   stack can be searched, and if a value is returned, it will written to
>   the output. **If no value is found on the stack, the key of the message
>   will be written out**.

Comment: Hi @RomanC, Thank you for your reply on this. I am not reading the value from properties file, but from the model class. Also as I mentioned in the question the member.address.city field has value as London and I see the same in debug mode. But still the name of the key is displayed on screen. Any idea why it is not printing london, but just printing the name of the key?

Comment: The value is not found then struts tag is printing the key, you can try to use `getText()` instead of the `s:text` tag.

Comment: Hi @RomanC, I see that <s:property /> tag is able to display the value fine. I found in the migration guide of Struts 2.5.8 that there was an improvement for <s:text/> tag so that it will not evaluate defaultMessage against a ValueStack by default. This might be the issue. Issue reference - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4711

Comment: If it's not evaluate the stack so how comes `getCity` method is called?

Comment: Valid point, but I am not sure why its behaving like this. For now I am just using `<s:property />` tag

Comment: It might be called by interceptor or whatever doesn't related to the problem if you can't explain it. The property tag might help if you can't use s:text, but it won't help. The problem is in loading property files to be used by i18n. You might try to load them yourself with i18n tag and use it inside.